# Aligning/stacking a large number of small but differently-sized div boxes in a clean way

Tags: html, css

I'm making a tag-cloud-esque display of words, each contained within small divs, and floated so that many appear on each line.  However, if I start changing the font size in some of the divs, the line structure gets broken up and huge gaps appear, as in this screenshot:

[image]

Can anyone offer any advice on how to resolve this?  I'm not looking to do anything fancy, like having multiple lines of smaller tags alongside larger ones:  I just want the divs to obey a normal looking line structure.

Here is the relevent css:

```
div.example {
background-color: #8C7D80;
padding: 2px;
margin: 2px;
float: left;
color: #96888B;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: could you provide [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try upping the line-height.
The brackets seem too be too large, thus breaking the line.

```
div.example {
  // other stuff here
  line-height: 1.5
}
```

Is it possible you have set a fixed line-height?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest setting the height explicitly and/or changing the line-height property.

```
div.example {
    background-color: #8C7D80;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 2px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    color: #96888B;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
```